# Jest toHaveBeenCalledWith is missing the second parameter

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am using Jest to test a function in my project, but `toHaveBeenCalledWith` is missing my second parameter `{}`:

```
describe("api.js", () => {
  it("should call callback with url", () => {
    const mockCallback = jest.fn();
    setAppBackend(mockCallback)("/duck");
    expect(mockCallback).toHaveBeenCalledWith("https://www.example.org/duck", {});
  });
});
```

```
  ● api.js › should call callback with url

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    - Expected
    + Received

    - "https://www.example.org/duck",
    + "http://www.example.org/duck",
      {},
```

Why is `toHaveBeenCalledWith` missing `{}`?

Comment: What happens in `setAppBackend`?

Comment: It's not telling you it's missing the second parameter, it's telling you the first one was wrong. Look at the + and -.

Comment: export const setAppBackend = (fn) => (endpoint, options = {}) =>
  fn(`https://www.example.org/${endpoint}`, { ...options });

Comment: Yes @jonrsharpe you are right.. I should have passed HTTP instead of https in the expected parameter. Thanks for your time.